# What are the free image hosting sites with APIs for upload images using urls

Tags: image, api, hosting

I'm looking for a free image hosting website that has an API with the capability of uploading images hosted in another site using the url.

Are there such free image hosting websites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the answer my self,

Imageshack.us comes with an API with the capability of uploading an hosted image using its URL (Transload).

Imageshcak API:
http://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/wiki/ImageshackAPI

There, when adding an image the the url parameter indicates that transload method is used instead of upload.

Comment: Note that you cannot use their service for commercial purposes

Comment: @Benjamin I think now you can: https://imageshack.com/business